# iOS 9 LaunchServices:Error:There is no registered handler for url scheme gplus

Tags: google-plus, ios9

```
-(void)opengPlus:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"gplus://"]];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It implies that the Google Plus app is not installed on the device and hence it can't handle the URL scheme here. This URL is supposed to be handled by the GPlus app.

Usually it happens in the simulator when testing so you can ignore such warnings. But if the device is having the said App installed, you will not see such warning.

**Update**:

Looks like the issue with new whitelisting of URL your app can open with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in plist.

Please refer : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html

Something like :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>     
     <string>whatsapp</string>
     <string>instagram</string>     
     <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Google+ is already installed in my device..it was working fine for ios8..but for ios9 I am getting this issue.